# Javascript: What should I use here to achieve my value (round,floor,ceil)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

I have different value like

```
5.5
13.56
45.70
58.89 (never go more than 60)
and many more ...
```

Suppose they are minutes. And I want their output in the round of nearest 15 division like

```
5.5 => 0
13.56 => 15
45.70 => 45
58.89 => 60
```

But I am not sure how can I achieve this rounded output. Please help me...

Comment: You'll need to write your own function to do this.  The built in javascript functions round, floor, ceil modify the number to a neighboring integer.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and how it has not worked. Till then, it is just another "give me the codez" question.

Answer (score 8):

There is not built in method to achieve that, however you can divide your number by 15, then use `round()` to round to nearest integer number and finally multiply by 15 to get the actual value:

```
var a = 13.56;
var dividedBy15 = a / 15;    // result is 0.904
var dividedAndRounded = Math.round(dividedBy15);   // result is 1
var finalResult = dividedAndRounded * 15;   // result is 15
```

Comment: @vikujangid If this worked for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
function roundToFifteen(num) {
  var mod = num % 15;

  if (mod < 7.5) {
    return num - mod;
  } else {
    return num + (15 - mod);
  }
}
```

Comment: actually `roundToFifteen(10) => 15` which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Whops! My mistake, sorry!

Comment: haha no worries you scared me for a sec I didn't test it tbh there could be an error.